# How do you expand all objects in the console view of chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a short cut for me to expand all these objects? I have attached a photo of what i would like to expand below. Any help would be amazing.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Run the following code in console of **devtools-on-devtools** (see below),

- modern Chrome: `$$('.console-view-object-properties-section').forEach(e => e.shadowRoot.querySelector('li').click())`
- old Chrome: `$$('.console-view-object-properties-section').forEach(e => e._section._objectTreeElement.expandRecursively())`

Then switch to the original devtools window.

#### How to open devtools-on-devtools:

1. Open devtools first and switch its `Dock side` in the menu to a detached (floating) window

[image]

2. in the now detached devtools press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> on MacOS,
   which will open **devtools-on-devtools** in a new window

---

For convenience you can save the code in [snippets](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/snippets) and run it later from there or by typing the snippet name in the commands palette (<kbd>Ctrl-P</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd-P</kbd> hotkey).

Comment: yo dawg, i heard you like devtools so we made devtools for your devtools so you can devtools your devtools while you devtools

Comment: I get "undefined" as response and nothing else happens.

Comment: @jumpjack, since it works for me I guess you didn't follow the instruction and instead used the main devtools window. If you did follow it, then there must be something else at play which needs an investigation in a separate question.

Comment: Here are the full instructions to open devtools-on-devtools: https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/inspecting-ash . The new code lives [here](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:third_party/devtools-frontend/src/front_end/console/ConsoleViewMessage.js;l=627;drc=3cc3af34a3799c1b1cf31a6d45ebc09143f03712) now.

Comment: `expandRecursively` is [here](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:third_party/devtools-frontend/src/front_end/elements/ElementsTreeElement.js;l=369;drc=213266c175555d0b2c309c9ecbdc58671728a024).

Comment: I also followed the instructions and it did not work for me I just got undefined

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all of these are logging the same object. This won't be useful to expand everything.

When you expand an object in the console, it shows you the object *at that point in time*, not the time it was logged. You should literally log the values you want to verify.

What exactly are you trying to achieve by debugging in this manner? There is probably a more efficient way.

Comment: Was just trying to view the data inside in more efficient way.