# How to expand all nested lazy-loaded links in a category view?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Here is the target page:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:CategoryTree?target=Category%3AComputing&mode=categories&namespaces=&title=Special%3ACategoryTree

Want to automatically expand all categories and subcategories.

Have read [How do you expand all objects in the console view of chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40117840/how-do-you-expand-all-objects-in-the-console-view-of-chrome)

Specifically, would like to expand the tree associated with `<div class="CategoryTreeResult"><div class="CategoryTreeSection">`

**How to** modify the solution from the Stackoverflow reference:

`$$('.console-view-object-properties-section').forEach(e => e._section._objectTreeElement.expandRecursively())`

to identify the target section and execute a command to expand all objects in the CategoryTreeSection?

Comment: That answer is not helpful here since a wiki page doesn't have expandRecursively() method implemented in devtools UI. You'll have to send a `click` to each link, wait for them to expand (setTimeout or MutationObserver) and repeat recursively.

Comment: would you show me how to do that in the chrome console? i can copy out the link text to put into a program that does what you describe. i just don't want to send the `click` manually; would like to have a repeatable solution for wiki pages.

Comment: ahhh  ... "each link". From HTML can only get the level 1 link. So your potential solution probably will only open to reveal a level 2 link, which will require the processes to be repeated. Am I understanding your point?

Comment: Uhm, if you know js, it should be pretty trivial (querySelectorAll + loop + click() + setTimeout/MutationObserver to repeat for the nested links). Maybe someone will post the code later.